# Using OpenCV 3.3.1 on Qt Creator 3.5.1 on Linux Mint (latest kernel)

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm trying too make a project in C++ using OpenCV via Qt Creator. I have not written any code yet as such, I'm just trying to get my project to access my openCV file.
I've tried a couple of methods I found on google, namely editing the  $PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable:

```
 echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
:/home/jess/Documents/SRI/TER/opencv-3.3.1`
```

(/home/jess... is where the openCV files are - as obtained and extracted from the website)
my .pro file looks like this:

```
QT       += core gui
# add open CV
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv-3.3.1

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = test
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

And when I build the project it tells me that openCV cannot be found (I have also tested using the name "openCV-3.3.1", same result)
if anyone can give me any pointers as to where I'm going wrong, I would be most grateful!

Comment: try change `opencv-3.3.1` to `opencv`

Comment: @eyllanesc I've tried that too, it doesn't change anything

Comment: where is opencv .pc located?

Comment: Oh, and "latest kernel"! That is so important. :)

Comment: Make sure that OpenCV is *installed* and not just present on that system. You can try either building OpenCV from source code (and finalize with `sudo make install`, find exact command from readme.md or so) or install it from dev.package (have not done that on Linux myself).

Comment: @AlexanderVX Hmm.. the readme doesn't have any installation instructions, but I think that may be the step I missed (I'll google some more).Not sure if that kernel comment was sarcastic or not, I genuinely don't know if it makes a difference...

Comment: @JessicaChambers https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-ubuntu/ and try to find `sudo make install` there.

Comment: @AlexanderVX Technically installation means copying the libs and headers to a default (for the system) location. So no, no need to install (how about multiple versions of OpenCV? ;)). All that is needed is to point  `qmake` (or `cmake` which I can totally recommend in this scenario since it has a much better support for this library in particular) to the right location where the `so` and `h` files are.

Comment: @rbaleksandar With Debian Package system there maybe a bit more actions to enable the package which is used like above. I do use it that way and not the way in the answer below. And it is easier and more portable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have OpenCV dev version installed on your system. Fortunately OpenCV can be found in official Ubuntu/Mint repositories. To start developing OpenCV apps you need to install its `-dev` version.

```
sudo apt install libopencv-dev
```

Ok. Now head to your project's `.pro` file and *link* your project to OpenCV.

```
LIBS += -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui
```

Make sure you've added all the OpenCV modules you need. OpenCV have the following modules:

> - **core** - a compact module defining basic data structures, including the dense multi-dimensional array Mat and basic functions used by all
>     other modules.
> - **imgproc** - an image processing module that includes linear and non-linear image filtering, geometrical image transformations (resize,
>     affine and perspective warping, generic table-based remapping), color
>     space conversion, histograms, and so on.
> - **video** - a video analysis module that includes motion estimation, background subtraction, and object tracking algorithms.
> - **calib3d** - basic multiple-view geometry algorithms, single and stereo camera calibration, object pose estimation, stereo correspondence
>     algorithms, and elements of 3D reconstruction.
> - **features2d** - salient feature detectors, descriptors, and descriptor matchers.
> - **objdetect** - detection of objects and instances of the predefined classes (for example, faces, eyes, mugs, people, cars, and so on).
> - **highgui** - an easy-to-use interface to simple UI capabilities.
> - **videoio** - an easy-to-use interface to video capturing and video codecs.
> - **gpu** - GPU-accelerated algorithms from different OpenCV modules.
> - **...** some other helper modules, such as FLANN and Google test wrappers, Python bindings, and others.

To link your project to another module just add a `-lopencv_<module>` to `LIBS`. That's it!

Comment: Note that the version in the repositories is often if not even always outdated. Unless you have a distro based on rolling releases (like Arch) with a constant update support for the OpenCV package, you will have to do the building and (opional) installing yourself.

Comment: @rbaleksandar Yes you're right. But it's not that outdated to not be usable for regular projects.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention which distro he/she is using plus the fact that building OpenCV is a great learning experience. But yeah, you are right that for most projects it's fine unless some latest feature or patch is required.